# Is there a way to add a subcollection to a document whose document id is auto-generated-id?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I am trying to create a kind of social networking application with Flutter and Firebase.
As shown in the image above, the document-id of each document in the 'users' collection is auto-generated-id,
and the FirebaseAuth's 'uid' is stored in the 'userId' field of each user document.
I would like to add a feature similar to twitter's follow function.

For example, if a user with document-id "4Fo5 ..." follows a user with document-id "0VkQ ..."
The specific method that comes to mind is
(a) Add the "followees" subcollection to the document of the user with document-id "4Fo5" and add the document of user "0VkQ" to it, and store "0VkQ"'s uid in the document.
(b) Add the "followers" subcollection to the document of the user with document id "0VkQ" and add the document of user "4Fo5" to it, and store "4Fo5"'s uid  int the document.
(c) Both (a) and (b).
(Question-1) Does "Is it necessary to do (c) or is either (a) or (b) sufficient?" Depends on what I want to display on the screen?
Or can I do it with (a) alone (or with (b) alone) regardless of the type of information I want to display?
If possible, I would like to keep the usage fee of the firestore low, but will there be a big difference between (a), (b), and (c) for that?

So I tried to do it, but I don't know how to add a subcollection in the current data structure shown at the very beginning.

I'll probably need code like this to add a subcollection:

```
instance.collection('users')
            .document('4Fo5ovHE2N6NzDLzVyoC')
            .collection('followees')
            .document('0VkQnHRrjcr5u54oZ5hA').set({
          //...
        });
```

'4Fo5ovHE2N6NzDLzVyoC'
'0VkQnHRrjcr5u54oZ5hA'
But for that I need to get the auto-generated-id above, is there a way to get the auto-generated-id in this data structure?

---

```
(await instance.collection('users').where(
          'userId',
          isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser.uid,
        ).get()).docs[0].data()
```

With the above code, I think I can get the document corresponding to user "4Fo5" in the users collection,
but the type I can get is QueryDocumentSnapshot type, not DocumentReference type.
So from here I don't think I can generate a "followees" subcollection.

(Question-2)Is there any way?
If there is no way to do that, it means that we can't add a subcollection to a document whose document-id is auto-generated-id after all,
so if we want to (or if we have to) use a subcollection, we shouldn't use auto-generated-id. Is that right?

(Question-3)As an alternative,In the "followee" field of the document for user "4Fo5"

```
[
    "O66Ay3xEwxZSjdrMvTfYk9fypj02", //←"0VkQ"'s uid
    "TWxyYAy7caWnrfdBxjIOCVkzApi2", //←other followee's uid
]
```

The above method of storing a list in the document also came to mind,
but when I look at the firebase documentation etc, storing a list seems to be problematic,
especially when the number of followees becomes large.
Is it still not a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll advise you use the user id as the document id since the autogenerated one can't be known by you and it's an extra query which is unnecessary especially as you want to "keep the usage fee of the firestore low".

For your question about adding a subcollection for "followers" and "followee", I'll say do both. It's simpler when you have specific subcollection for each feature.

I'll prefer to add documents to the subcollection than to store the followers/followees in a list because you easily query documents, check if they exist and perform other operations without having to fetch the entire list.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.   It's more intuitive to use uid as the documenti-id, isn't it?
However, I think that would be a big disadvantage of auto-generated-id, but is there a situation where auto-generated-id is used?
Does that mean using auto-generated-id when storing less important data that doesn't have a uid or filepath?

Comment: Auto-generated IDs are appropriate in situations where you don't have a special/separate ID for the document - like storing a list of messages or books. In that case, you can use the autogenerated ID as the ID for the document if you want to use that to identify it.

Comment: Also, if you take a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data, you'll see there's no reference to not using auto-generated IDs as being a disadvantage. It's up to the developer to choose the one that makes their work easier.

Answer (score 0):

ye it is the way
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(id).collection(your_sub_collection).doc().set({});
it is the way